# PARTITION BY a rolling or surrounding one month period

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I need to use

```
PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY monthperiod ORDER BY probability ASC) AS  Rank
```

The following code is part of a larger query and it is close, but if I get a date close to the beginning of the month, I believe it is going to rank against the rest of the month instead of two weeks before and two weeks after.

```
SELECT
    *, 
    PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY monthperiod ORDER BY probability ASC) AS Rank
FROM
    (SELECT
         *,
         FLOOR(DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]) / 2) AS MonthPeriod,
         CONCAT(YEAR([Date]), DATEPART(MONTH, [Date])) YearMonth
     FROM 
         database.schema.table AS t) monthperiod
WHERE
    ISNULL(Rank, 1) >= 0.90
```

The results probability should be ranked by how that probability ranks up to all of the IDs within that GroupID in the surrounding month (two weeks after and two weeks before). This is why the rank is different even though the probabilities might be.

```
ID  GroupID Date    Probability Rank
--------------------------------------
8403    581 7/12/2018   0.75     0.98 
2679    581 7/12/2018   0.85     0.99 
5899    581 7/12/2018   0.95     1.00 
7902    960 8/15/2019   0.85     0.98 
3659    960 8/15/2019   0.75     0.96 
1406    960 8/15/2019   0.95     1.00 
8241    125 9/23/2020   0.95     0.96 
3240    125 9/23/2020   0.75     0.90 
4074    125 9/23/2020   0.85     0.92
```

Forgive me if this ends up being simple. I did as much searching and varying my search as I could and did not find a solution. I'm still new to SQL, so if someone more experienced has a creative solution, that would be great.

Comment: Hi, it would really help if you can add a few lines of data and from it what would be the desired result and please don't add images, add it as text so one can copy and try on their environment.

Comment: Also `[Date]` is a syntax error, unless you live in microsoftland. (and: `select *,` is a red flag)

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am currently adding sample data. Please come back and check! @JorgeCampos

Comment: I think of ranks as being integers, not ratios.  Can you be clearer on what the calculation is?

Comment: It is a percent rank so not an integer

Comment: Is the data you added the data you have or the resulting data? See here how to structure your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557 there is no better explanation than an actual set of data and the desired outcome. You see Without it a lot of people is confused with what you are asking.